# Js lodash sort by deeper field

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects annd i want to sort by deeper field. How can i do this?

```
var array =    
   {
     "id": 27,
     "name": "La Primita Product",
     "lottery": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "La Primitiva",
        "jackpotAmount": 10000,
      }
   },
    {
     "id": 28,
     "name": "La Primita Product",
     "lottery": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "La Primitiva",
        "jackpotAmount": 10000,
    }
```

How can i sort by lottery.jackpotAmount?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) you can pass callback as a second argument, like this

```js
var array = [{
  "id": 27,
  "name": "La Primita Product",
  "lottery": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "La Primitiva",
    "jackpotAmount": 10000,
  }
}, {
  "id": 28,
  "name": "La Primita Product",
  "lottery": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "La Primitiva",
    "jackpotAmount": 10,
  }
}];

array = _.sortBy(array, function (el) {
  return el.lottery.jackpotAmount;
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```