# lodash order by array of object is not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
let arr = 
  [{
    "goodreadsId": "1531073",
    "books": {
      "title": "pensée antique",
      "ratings_count": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "goodreadsId": "1377520",
    "books": {
      "title": "Why",
      "ratings_count": "2"
    }
  }]
```

I did `_.sortBy(arr, 'books.ratings_count')` I expect the ratings count of 2 will be sorted at the first but it didn't. I also tried `_.sortBy(arr, 'books.ratings_count', 'desc')` but it doesn't work, any clue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Js lodash sort by deeper field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526612/js-lodash-sort-by-deeper-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are going to sort array in `DESC` order by `ratings_count`.

In this case, you should use `_.orderBy` function. (`_.sortBy` function supports sorting on `ASCENDING` order).

```js
let arr = [{
    "goodreadsId": "1531073",
    "books": {
      "title": "pensée antique",
      "ratings_count": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "goodreadsId": "1377520",
    "books": {
      "title": "Why",
      "ratings_count": "2"
    }
  }
];

console.log(_.orderBy(arr, "books.ratings_count", ['desc']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = 
  [{
    "goodreadsId": "1531073",
    "books": {
      "title": "pensée antique",
      "ratings_count": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "goodreadsId": "1377520",
    "books": {
      "title": "Why",
      "ratings_count": "2"
    }
  }]
  
const sorted = _.sortBy(arr, el => -el.books.ratings_count);

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```